# Precompile hang with ckeditor gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I'm using `Rails 3.2.13` and `Ruby 1.9.3p374`

For more detail see my [github issue](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linked issue in the question](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/397) describes the problem. As for a walkthrough solution:

Delete first, blank line, if applicable from:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-4.0.8/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/build-config.js
```

Add this nonsense javascript:

```
var myvarharhar = new Boolean(1);
```

to

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-4.0.8/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/application.js
```

so that there is some actual js rather than just comments in that file

in `config/environments/production.rb` setting `config.assets.compile = true` doesn't seem to matter, it works either way

`ckeditor/init.js` takes ages to compile

This might not work for you - BUT here is the technique I used to solve the problem, which you can use:

Is a separate pane/terminal-window, `tail -f log/production.log` to see the log of your app whilst you precompile with `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, look at the log, at what its been stuck on for a while, ie what js file is at the bottom of the log, then go to that file and see if there is whitespace at the start of the file or no javascript present (only comments) and bodge it up.

The cavalry will come soon, in the form of pull requests etc but for now this bodge will work =)